# javsacript / node.js await one more task makes it unblock?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I use `while(true)` to simulate the js thread blocking as below

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(new Date(), 'interval');
}, 500);

while (true) {
  console.log(new Date(), 'while true');
}
```

In the above code, we cannot see `interval` printed on the terminal because the call stack busy at executing what's in the `while(true)`.

But I can see `interval` in the below code by adding one more `await` in the `while(true)`.

```js
main();

async function main() {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(new Date(), 'interval');
  }, 500);
  while (true) {
    console.log(new Date(), 'while true');
    await wait();
  }

  function wait() {
    return new Promise(ok => setTimeout(ok, 0));
  }
}
```

Why adding one `await` in the `while(true)` would make js main thread have spare time to  execute the `interval` ?

I usually use this image while thinking of async behaviour in js. I'm thinking the call stack is full of what's in the `while(true)` no matter we put a `await` or not.

[image]

event loop image from

https://medium.com/@swarajgandhi/what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway-fc5a687a9577

Comment: It's not the `await`, it's the `setTimeout` that allows the interval callback to run

Comment: Could you please try to "phrase" what your current thinking model is? We certainly don't read this image the same way (and visually impaired folks would also greatly benefit from it).

Answer (score 1):

> javsacript / node.js await one more task makes it unblock?

It depends upon what the task is that you're awaiting.

> Why adding one await in the while(true) would make js main thread have spare time to execute the interval ?

Here's a simplified sequence of steps that happens with this loop:

```
  while (true) {
    console.log(new Date(), 'while true');
    await wait();
  }
```

1. Log the date
2. call `wait()`
3. When executing `wait()` call `setTimeout(ok, 0)`
4. Return unresolved promise from `wait()`.
5. `await` that unresolved promise.
6. Your `while` loop is now suspended until that promise resolves.
7. Control goes back toward the event loop upon the function suspension at the `await`.
8. The first thing that is checked is a few higher priority things like the promise job queue.  Nope, nothing there yet.
9. OK, go back to the main event loop.  This main event loop has multiple steps in its cycleand one of those steps is for timers.
10. When the event loop gets to the timer stage, see what the oldest timer-related event is and call its callback.  Hmmm, if there was already an overdue `setInterval()` timer waiting to run, it will get to run.  After it runs, check for any other pending timers and run them.
11. If there's no overdue `setInterval()` waiting to run, then the `setTimeout(ok, 0)` should now be ready the run.  The event loop calls its callback which resolves the promise we created earlier.
12. Now, there is something in the promise job queue so service that.  This will resume the `main` function call on the `await` where it left off in step #6, and the `while` loop gets to run another cycle (starting at #1).

Because of step #10, you can see that at some point, there will be an overdue `setInterval()` waiting to run and it will be in line in front of the most recent `setTimeout(ok, 0)` so it will get to run.  After it runs, the next `setTimeout(ok, 0)` will get its turn to run.

Thus, you get to see the `setInterval()` results when you `await` something that is only resolved when a `setTimeout()` fires.

---

So, put even simpler.  The `setInterval()` timer and the `setTimeout()` timer are served by the same part of the event loop.  So, the same code in the event loop that allows your `setTimeout()` to run which will resolve the promise you are awaiting also allows the `setInterval()` timer to run.  So, when you await the promise that gets resolved by a `setTimeout()` you're making your code wait until the event loop gets to the part where it serves timers and while it's doing that, it's going to serve any `setInterval()` firing that was already waiting before you registered your `setTimeout()`.  It won't serve only your `setTimeout()` without also serving any already waiting `setInterval()`.

So, it's not so much about "spare time" in the event loop, but about ordering in the event loop.  A `setInterval()` that is already overdue will get served by the event loop before your `setTimeout(ok, 0)`.  So, the promise in your `wait()` function won't get resolved until after any `setInterval()` that was already waiting to run gets to run, thus allowing them to interleave and both get to run.

---

As a test and a puzzle for further understanding, try changing to this:

```
function wait() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

This will return an immediately resolved promise which will not let the `setInterval()` get a chance to run because resolved promises get served before the main event loop that handles timers like `setInterval()`. So, you never allow the event loop to get around to serving timers as you starve it by constantly giving it a resolved promise to serve.

Note, you will generally not want to program this way (with a loop on an already resolved promise) because you are starving other parts of the event loop.  This was just a demo for illustration purposes.

Comment: Reworked the explanation to try to make it both more detailed and simpler to follow.